# How to format date in Teradata where some fields only have zero?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I have a field named myfakedate [Decimal, 7,0)] where the field returns values as (ex. 20201205, 20230416, 20170509).

My goal is to return them as 2020-12-05, 2023-04-16 & 2017-05-09.

There are a few records where there is no date and that record has a '0' (without ''). What I wrote below converts the date as what I want. The issue is when I add it to my WHERE statement. I get a 'Month of year must be in range 1-12'.

Here is what I have:

`To_Date(LPAD(TO_CHAR(CAST(mytable.myfakedate AS INT)), 8, '0'), 'yymmdd' As MynewDate`

As I said, the conversion from 20201205 to 2020-12-05 works.

When I add 'MynewDate' in the Where statement I get 'Month of year must be in range 1-12'.

I pulled all values for myfakedate and all months are 1-12. I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `0` is not a valid date in Teradata/Standard SQL, you need to NULL it.

Your `to_date` will not work as it uses two-digit years.

If all other dates exist the most efficient solution is based on Teradata's internal storage of dates:

```
Cast(NullIf(mytable.myfakedate,0) - 19000000 AS DATE)
```

But if some bad dates exists:

```
TryCast(Trim(mytable.myfakedate (Format '9999-99-99')) AS DATE)
```

Comment: I thought trycast didn't work when you specify a date format? If I run `select TryCast(Trim('1900-01-01' (Format 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS DATE)`, I get a 3527 error.
 `

Comment: It doesn't, I got the same error.

Comment: @Andrew The format is applied to the numeric value within the trim, resulting in a string which can be trycasted :-)

Comment: @blue Show your WHERE

Comment: @dnoeth - don't know if it's a version thing, but just the trim with format (`select   trim('1900-01-01' (format 'yyyy-MM-dd'))` ) fails with the same error for me.

Comment: @Andrew You trim a *string* and try to apply a *date* format: `trim(DATE '1900-01-01' (format 'yyyy-MM-dd'))`